# Https:// to Http rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

I have a site that insists on using *https* when linking to my site even though my site has no SSL, so how can I rewrite that to *http* when this link is clicked so that the user doesn't see the ugly warning that most browsers are using now when an *https* link points to an *http* only site with no SSL?

Here is the code I'm using in `.htaccess` and feel the code is correct but I'm still getting the warning that "Your connection is not secure":

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^tag(/.*|$) /softball-tag$1 [NC,QSA,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The code that should fix this in the above code but isn't working is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well If you don't have HTTPS no HTTPS requests will reach your server so you will not be able to detect them in the first place?  If they *do* reach your site but receive a certificate warning there is absolutely nothing you can do except fixing that issue by deploying a valid certificate which will give you HTTPS & remove the problem.

Comment: What you ask is impossible. You CAN NOT trick a browser into that. For very good reasons browsers will warn their users.

Comment: Why don't you simply install a certificate and offer encrypted access, which is the standard these days?

Comment: Fortunately it's impossible!

Comment: @arkascha why should I waste the money encrypting images and text? I have no user accounts or eCommerce that I need to protect on this site.

Comment: Money? ssl certificates are free these days. Take a look at the LetsEncrypt project.

Comment: The question is not to be secure or not. The question is to go back without letting the user know !

Comment: @arkascha thanks. I'll look into it but believe that Godaddy shared cPanel hosting won't allow LetsEncrypt, so I'm back to paying for it.

Comment: Then you can still get a free ssl certificate from startSSL.

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess seems good. Are your sure that .htaccess is enabled?

For instance if you are using Apache you should add:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: I think it is enabled... the other rewrite `^tag(/.*|$)` is working.

Comment: I've just tested an .htaccess with only the HTTPS rules and it works.